# Pass a collection of objects from controller into array in ember view

Tags: ember.js

I was wondering what the best way to pass an array of model objects into a new array defined in a view is in ember?

Basically: There is a bunch of people via an association in the controller:

```
App.MeetingsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['people'],
    init: function() {
        var people = this.get('controllers.people'); 
        people.set('content', App.Person.find());
    }
});
```

Then inside the template for that controller I am defining a view. Inside this view I want to get all of the people set on the controller and put them in an array. When one is selected I want to move it to a new array. Simple enough, but I cannot work out the process for doing this.

```
App.SearchField = Ember.View.extend({
    availablePeople: [],
    selectedPeople: [],
    init: function() {
        // What needs to go here to push objects from controller.people to availablePeople? 
    }
});
```

I have tried various things using this.get('controller.people') and pushObjects, but I never seem to be able to iterate over the list in the template of the view:

```
{{#each view.availablePeople}}
    <li>
        {{ name }}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

What am I missing?
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: why do you have `data` in your views? is it transient data?

Comment: Yes, I want to define it in the view so that each instance of the view has it's own collection of people, sorted between two arrays for each view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this on the controller (it would have been nice to have decoupled but alas), using a computed property like so:

```
availablePeople: function() {
    var people = App.Person.find();
    var selectedPeople = this.get('content.people'); 
    return people.filter(function(x) { return selectedPeople.indexOf(x) < 0 });
}.property('content.people.length')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your case, the best way to have access to the controller in your view is to provide a controller for that view which can be referenced from another controller without problems, let me explain this in code:

First, create a controller for your `SearchField` view:

```
App.SearchFieldController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['people'], //define here all controller that you need access to
  availablePeople: [],
  selectedPeople: [],
  init: function() {
    var people = this.get('controllers.people'); 
    // set your array's...
  }
});
```

Then change your `SearchField` view to `SearchFieldView`:

```
App.SearchFieldView = Ember.View.extend({
  ...
});
```

After that, you template need's some change to:

```
{{#each availablePeople}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

If you have followed Ember's naming conventions, then the `SearchFieldController` has been instantiated by Ember automatically and used for the `SearchFieldView` and through the `needs` in your `SearchFieldController` the access to your `PeopleController` is also guaranteed.

Hope it helps